# Hotkey for changing pivot center?

Tags: shortcut, 3d-cursor

I frequently go forth and back between "3D cursor" and "Median point" as pivot center.

Are there any hotkeys for this?

[image: Pivot point options]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Blender's Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html?#pivot-point) gives you the answer:

Bounding Box Center: <kbd>**,**</kbd>
3D Cursor: <kbd>**.**</kbd>
Individual Origins: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>**.**</kbd>
Median Point: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>**,**</kbd>
Active Element: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>**.**</kbd>

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't know it either, so I googled it. I don't change the pivot point often enough to be bothered by not knowing though.

Comment: I love you big time

Comment: Oops, that's a dead link now

Comment: You can change it under *User Preferences* -> *Input* -> *3D View* -> *3D View (Global)* -> *Context Set Enum* and  *Context Toggle*

Comment: What would be nice is a shortcut to "toggle" between the different modes... Does it exists ?

Comment: on Mac, the period (3D Cursor) doesn't work with my keyboard, so I changed it to semi-colon (;) (thanks Azul Shiva).

Answer (score 1):

With the ***UiPieMenuOfficial Addon*** ,pivot point menu can be easily accessed with the ***period "." key.***

[image]

Comment: In Blender 3.0 the older accepted answer did not work. This worked for me and I did not have to enable the menu. Didn't notice your answer. Mental note. Scroll down.
Discovery path:
Edit >> User Preferences >> Keymap >> Type "pivot" in the Keymap search box.