# Hotkey for toggling pivot center?

Tags: shortcut

Hi read about the [hotkeys for changing pivot center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26142/hotkey-for-changing-pivot-center), but is there another hotkey to toggle between those modes ?
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there isn't one, but there should be.  I'm stuck with "." and Ctrl ",".

Answer (score 1):

With the 'Pie Menu: UI Pie Menu Official' addon enabled, press the semicolon ";" key to change the the pivot point with a Pie interface.